# How to hide and unhide rows on protected sheet, without error 1004?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting `error 1004` when hiding and unhiding rows on a sheet.

This sheet is protected but does allow the user to format rows which allows the user to hide and unhide rows.

Although the code does work, it gives an `error 1004` telling me the sheet is protected which I need to get rid of. I believe the issue is because I'm selecting the cells I want to hide/unhide. How do I just hide/unhide the cell range?

```
Sub Show_menu()
    Rows("20:20").Select
    Rows("20:44").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("45:45").Select
    Rows("45:128").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: do you know the password to unprotect?

Comment: of course, But I want this to work when the sheet is protected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Sub Show_menu()
Sheets("yoursheetname").Unprotect Password:="abc"
    Rows("20:20").Select
    Rows("20:44").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("45:45").Select
    Rows("45:128").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Sheets("yoursheetname").Protect Password:="abc", AllowFormattingRows:=True
End Sub
```

**Appended**:

```
AllowFormattingCells:=True ' to allow formatting
```

and

```
Sheets("yoursheetname").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells ' to allow unlocked cell in protected book
```

Comment: Sorry this may be my fault and probably need to give more information, the excel sheet im using this on is something I will be sending out to customer and there is certain parts of the sheet that are protected, I dont want it prompt the user to unlock the sheet I want it to execute the macro with out the error 1004 and keep the sheet protected. hope this make more sense now

Comment: when does your sub operate? by pressing on a button or how?

Comment: This works like a charm, sorry another quick addition which I didnt realize till you added AllowFormattingRows what is the correct syntax for Allowing Select unlocked cells and Format Cells?

Comment: Glad it worked. See appended answer for your last query.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem (1004 on hide/show macro). For me the issue was that cell comments (and other objects) were placed in the cells affected by the hide/show macro, in particular when the object property was set to "Don't move or resize with cells". The first time this happened it took a while to spot as all comments were hidden...
For me the fix was to change the property, or to move or delete the object. /T