# Macro to Hide Unhide columns in excel based on certain cell conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I want to hide a specific column based on value in a certain cell. For example, in my code I want to hide entire "F" column if cell value in F26 is less than 0.75. Likewise, hide "G" column if value in G26 is less than 0.75 and so on.

```
Sub HideColumn1()
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In Range("F26:AB26")
        If cel.Value < 0.75 Then
            Columns(cel).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            Columns(cel).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Currently my code is giving me `1004 error` on line:

```
Columns(cel).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Getting rid of error 1004 With Hide and unhide Macros when sheets protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906689/excel-vba-getting-rid-of-error-1004-with-hide-and-unhide-macros-when-sheets-prot)

Comment: `cel.EntireColumn.Hidden = True` should do it.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thank you :)

Comment: `cel.EntireColumn.Hidden = (cel.Value < 0.75)` is a little more concise

Answer (score -1):

Please try "On Error resume next" if you want to ignore the Error.